# INNER JOIN not working with PHP PDO MySQL

Tags: php, pdo, inner-join

Trying to get an INNER JOIN to work is driving me insane, so I'm very much hoping that someone can help me out here.

I have two tables in a database:

```
BranchEmployees
DepartmentEmployees
```

Both tables have a column called `EmpID` so I can track which employees are assigned to which department and to which branch. I'm making a report that finds which employees are assigned to a specified department and branch, excluding all the rest so an `INNER JOIN` query seems like the logical solution, but we just cannot get it to work. We keep getting the fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in ...

$query="SELECT DepartmentEmployees.EmpID FROM DepartmentEmployees INNER JOIN BranchEmployees ON  DepartmentEmployees.EmpID=BranchEmployees.EmpID";

$connect=$cdb->query($query);
$EmployeeList[$m]=$connect->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Does it matter that it's on a shared server when trying to INNER JOIN tables? I don't think it should from what I can read, but you never know.

Comment: Where is the `fetchAll` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourDBName", 'root', 'pass', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") );
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

    $sql = 'SELECT de.EmpID FROM DepartmentEmployees as de INNER JOIN BranchEmployees as be ON de.EmpID = be.EmpID';

    $sth = $db->query($sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    # There was an error, die
    die('There was an error.');
}

$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

var_dump($result);
?>
```

Just change this line for db connection, query should work;

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourDBName", 'root', 'pass', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") );
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but it results with a fatal error on the $db->setAttribute line:

Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in /hermes/bosweb26a/b1552

Comment: It sounds like your PDO module is not loaded !

Comment: This means you are not connecting to the database. Look for PHP warnings and errors; double-check your host, database, user and pass; make sure your mysql server is even listening on an outside port; make sure there's no firewall between you.

Comment: Major appologies! That was dumb on my part. Copied existing DB connection code, so DB handle was named differently. This code IS NOW WORKING. Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch: There are a gazillion employees and the fetchAll() exceeds some memory threshold. Your SQL query will get every single department_employee<->branch_employee mapping, but only the EmpID field, which doesn't seem very useful. Is that what you want?

The first thing I like to do when diagnosing SQL problems is to format the SQL to be readable:

```
    SELECT DepartmentEmployees.EmpID 
      FROM DepartmentEmployees 
INNER JOIN BranchEmployees 
        ON DepartmentEmployees.EmpID=BranchEmployees.EmpID
```

Now, fire up a MySQL client directly against the database (ie not via PHP) and confirm that you get the results you expect.

If the query works outside of PHP PDO (it should, if table and field names are correct), then it has to be an issue with that wrapper. Can you post a stack trace?

Also, for testing, try limiting the result set and see if it fixes it (not sure what the PDO syntax for LIMIT is, but in MySQL it would be 'LIMIT 30')

Comment: There is no 'PDO syntax' for limit, it would simply be attached to query string.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but there are only a handful of records in each table (under 20).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either your PDO module is not installed correctly our you PDO construction is not working correctly.

use [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to check for the first problem and the following for the second :

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); // init your connection here
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die ('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```